# Gurggle noise 02 for escape

Tags: ford, noise, escape

I have a 2002 ford escape I was driving and heard a gurggling noice very low. No overheating and didn't hear anything when I cut the car off it doesn't stay. Could the be a gasket?

Answer (score 1):

The vehicle likely has air trapped in the cooling system, perhaps in the heater core in the dashboard. Gurgling results, and can often be heard in the passenger compartment.

You will have to bleed the cooling system to remove the air. I'm not familiar with the cooling system on this vehicle, and can't advise how to do it.